# web API2 Http get request status pending

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I created a web api 2 REST service (I use attribute routing) and it's working fine in my local machine. But when I hosted it, the HTTP Get request is pending. (I have installed .NET framework 4.5.1 in the host server)
Any idea why? 
Thanks

Comment: Is any error raised?

Comment: Is your Api hosted in IIS or self hosted?

Comment: No errors, in the Network tab (Chrome) it just say the status is Pending. No time out as well

Comment: Same with me. After 5 minutes idle time, I tried to upload a file but the status is forever pending.